# Split a CSV into pieces and pass each of them as an argument to a command

Tags: r, bash

```
awk -v m=3 '
    (NR==1){h=$0;next}
    (NR%m==2) { close(f); f=sprintf("%s.%0.5d",FILENAME,++c); print h > f }
    {print > f}' file.csv
```

The above code can split `file.csv` into pieces of 3 lines while remaining the header line for each piece. If I don't want to write these smaller CSVs into files, but rather want to pass them one a time directly as an argument to a command, is it possible?

```
sbatch mybash.sh ${csv_piece}
```

I suppose that I can receive the CSV pieces as arguments in R script:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `xargs` command? That is typically used for this kind of thing.

Comment: @DanielHollas I'm unfamiliar with bash, so I don't really know how to combine awk and xargs to achieve this

Comment: You have a file and you want to process 3 lines at a time in R?

Comment: @RuiBarradas In fact I want to start several jobs on clusters using sbatch command, I want to split a file in to pieces to mimick parallel computing

Comment: You may want to explore something like: `while read VAR1 VAR2 VAR3; do echo $VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3; done < <(COMMAND)` where COMMAND outputs your arguments. I'm using `echo` here as an example, but you can substitute `mybatch.sh` (as long as it supports arguments). (I don't think you need R)

Comment: pleaee update the question with a set of sample input (eg, a few lines from the `file.csv`), the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output